# Power Query Convert Records in List to Columns

Tags: powerquery, m

I have a list of JSON documents that I'm trying to convert into rows in Power Query. I'm struggling though as the values I need are records, in a list, inside a column the record. Anything that starts getting close to what I need gets horrendously complex

A single record looks like this:

```
{
    "key_as_string": "2020-02-25T23:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1582671600000,
    "doc_count": 1086187,
    "attack_types": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "attack-sqli",
                "doc_count": 380989
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-protocol",
                "doc_count": 8195
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-xss",
                "doc_count": 1216
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rce",
                "doc_count": 258
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-disclosure",
                "doc_count": 157
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-lfi",
                "doc_count": 24
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-generic",
                "doc_count": 17
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rfi",
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to turn it into this:
[image]
The 2nd row shown here is just an example of what a 2nd record would look like, for clarity.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started with this JSON, saved in a file called test.json, to ensure I would see how things worked with two records:

```
    [{
    "key_as_string": "2020-02-25T23:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1582671600000,
    "doc_count": 1086187,
    "attack_types": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "attack-sqli",
                "doc_count": 380989
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-protocol",
                "doc_count": 8195
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-xss",
                "doc_count": 1216
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rce",
                "doc_count": 258
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-disclosure",
                "doc_count": 157
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-lfi",
                "doc_count": 24
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-generic",
                "doc_count": 17
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rfi",
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "key_as_string": "2020-02-25T22:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 158267000000,
    "doc_count": 1086186,
    "attack_types": {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
        "buckets": [
            {
                "key": "attack-sqli",
                "doc_count": 384419
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-protocol",
                "doc_count": 2046
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-xss",
                "doc_count": 1504
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rce",
                "doc_count": 198
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-disclosure",
                "doc_count": 120
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-lfi",
                "doc_count": 16
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-generic",
                "doc_count": 200
            },
            {
                "key": "attack-rfi",
                "doc_count": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}]
```

The I used the GUI to derive this M code, which seems to work:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("MYFILEPATH\test.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"key_as_string", "key", "doc_count", "attack_types"}, {"key_as_string", "key", "doc_count", "attack_types"}),
    #"Expanded attack_types" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Column1", "attack_types", {"doc_count_error_upper_bound", "sum_other_doc_count", "buckets"}, {"doc_count_error_upper_bound", "sum_other_doc_count", "buckets"}),
    #"Expanded buckets" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Expanded attack_types", "buckets"),
    #"Expanded buckets1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded buckets", "buckets", {"key", "doc_count"}, {"key.1", "doc_count.1"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Expanded buckets1", List.Distinct(#"Expanded buckets1"[key.1]), "key.1", "doc_count.1"),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"key", "attack-sqli", "attack-protocol", "attack-xss", "attack-rce", "attack-disclosure", "attack-lfi", "attack-generic", "attack-rfi"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Other Columns",{{"key", Order.Descending}})
in
    #"Sorted Rows"
```

Just cut and paste the above M code into your Advanced editor. *Replace MYFILEPATH with your file path.*

I got this result:

[image]

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly what I was trying to achieve!! Thanks @marc-pincince !